# TYPO3 Bootstrap error after upgrading from 4.5 to 6.2.9

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typo3-6.2.x

After upgrading from 4.5.40 to 6.2.9 I get this error

Fatal error: Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap' not found in /var/www/my_domain.dk/public_html/typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/index_ts.php on line 32

What did I miss to do?

I haven't installed the Bootstrap Package. Should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Core\Bootstrap is not the same as a twitter bootstrap packages, so no, You don't have to install it.

Try the following:
- upgrade all your extensions and look in the install tool for broken extensions.
- clear the cache (in the install tool)
- remove EVERYTHING from inside typo3temp

If the error still exist, take a look in your error log file to see what invokes the error.

Comment: It seems like something is rewritten in the typo3temp-folder when I delete it. This is what I get form the error-log: [24-Feb-2015 19:40:06 Europe/Copenhagen] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap' not found in /var/www/billundfriluft.dk/public_html/typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/index_ts.php on line 32
[24-Feb-2015 19:40:06 Europe/Copenhagen] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap' not found in /var/www/billundfriluft.dk/public_html/typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/index_ts.php on line 32

Comment: I have now removed every extension, that is not standard. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have taken the new index.php file from the new typo3_src. If you don't use symlinks that's easy to forget. And of course clearing cache (typo3temp/*).